# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate - update one field using another

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider this schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    user_id: {type:String},
    previous_selection: {type:String},
    current_selection: {type:String}
});
```

I need to write a function, which will update the value of `previous_selection` with the value of `current_selection` for the given `user_id`.

Is there any way of doing this with `findOneAndUpdate`?

Something like -

```
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { user_id: id }, 
        { $set: {"previous_selection": current_selection }},
        {}, 
        callback
);
```

Or is there a better way to implement this? Will I have to do a `find()` and then update?

Comment: you cannot update a field with another one in single update you have to call a find method to accomplish this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your concern you can do this to update entire collection.

```
db.MyModel.find({}).snapshot().forEach(
function (elem) {
    db.MyModel.update(
        {
            _id: elem._id
        },
        {
            $set: {
                "previous_selection": elem.current_selection
            }
        }
    );
});
```

else you can find by id and can update with respective current_selection.

Comment: What does .snapshot() do?

Comment: It simply prevents returning the doc more than once.

Comment: Nice; but returning the same doc more than once, or duplicates?